# Docker install on windows failed (4.12.0): AutoStartAction failed: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I get the following error when trying to install Docker Desktop (4.12.0), my machine rebooted and I guess docker tried to update itself and failed, not I cant install at all.
Any ideas? Below is the install log:

```
 Started on: 2022/10/04 11:10:35.716
File: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Docker\install-log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" 
[11:10:35.903][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader] No install path specified, looking for default installation registry key
[11:10:35.903][Program] No installation found
[11:10:36.138][InstallWorkflow] Cancel pending background download
[11:10:36.169][InstallWorkflow] Using package: res:DockerDesktop
[11:10:36.169][InstallWorkflow] Downloading
[11:10:40.517][InstallWorkflow] Extracting manifest
[11:10:41.588][InstallWorkflow] Manifest found: version=69879, displayVersion=4.1.1, channelUrl=https://desktop.docker.com/win/main/amd64/appcast.xml
[11:10:41.589][InstallWorkflow] Checking prerequisites
[11:10:42.022][InstallWorkflow] Unpacking artifacts
[11:12:27.478][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[11:12:32.128][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[11:12:36.717][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction
[11:12:37.708][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction
[11:12:37.713][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Removing service
[11:12:37.717][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Creating service
[11:12:39.270][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[11:12:39.324][InstallWorkflow-ShortcutAction] Creating shortcut: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Docker Desktop.lnk/Docker Desktop
[11:12:39.339][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[11:12:39.340][InstallWorkflow-ShortcutAction] Creating shortcut: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Docker Desktop.lnk/Docker Desktop
[11:12:39.342][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction
[11:12:39.362][InstallWorkflow] Installation failed
Exception type: System.Exception, Exception message: Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: The parameter is incorrect.
, StackTrace:
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
[11:12:39.365][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[11:12:39.365][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ShortcutAction
[11:12:39.366][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction
[11:12:40.377][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction
[11:12:40.378][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[11:12:40.379][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[11:12:40.380][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.UnpackArtifactsStep
[11:12:40.397][FileSystem] Deleting C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
[11:12:40.573][FileSystem] Deleted C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker successfully
[11:12:40.573][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ExtractManifestStep
[11:12:40.574][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.DownloadStep
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of machine restarts the error went away